# RequestMethod.GET not getting envoked

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

My code looks as follows:

```
@Controller
public class ImporterErrorsController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "importerErrors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String importerErrors(WebRequest webRequest, Model model) {
    return "importerErrors";
  }
}
```

And

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a th:href="@{/importerErrors}">Errors</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

For some reason when I click the errors button in the navbar, the method importErrors does not get invoked. I have successfully run some POST methods inside a form but for some reason i cannot get the GET method to get invoked. Additionally, I managed to do something similar in a different project.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you add an example of the actual request being done? For example by checking the Network from the Web Developers Tools in a browser.

Comment: the request looks as follows: Request URL: http://localhost:5000/importerErrors
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:5000

Comment: Thanks. And what is the response? Also can you confirm your server is running on port 5000?

Comment: I do not get anything in the response, certainly not "importerErrors". I don't hit that method at all. And yes, it is running on port 5000.

Comment: What if you try in the terminal `curl localhost:5000/importerErrors`?

Comment: I believe you are missing a "/" on value = "importerErrors". Adding it should make it work.